# k2: How to remove default term "Children Categories" and give it a different title

Tags: k2

Implemented k2 extension on client's website. Would like to know how to remove default term "Children Categories" and give it a different title (http://www.wilddusk.com/wild-india).

Answer (score 4):

Dont change the orginal language files of an extensions. All your changes will be lost at the next update.

Instead use **Language overrides** 
a tutorial how to use is there : http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/joomla-3/languages/overrides

Answer (score 0):

It's in K2 language file (/language/en-GB/en-GB.com_k2.ini).
Search 'CHILDREN CATEGORIES' and change the text whatever you want.